# Applying one frailty value to all observations in mixed effects cox regression and then recalculating the survival probability

Tags: probability, mixed-model, survival, cox-model, frailty

I want to test the difference in survival probabilities for if every observation in my dataset was part of the frailty group with the worst or best frailty value. I want to calculate the survival probability for the maximum 'time' in my data. (This is just a demonstrative thought experiment to show how the random effects influence the outcome).

For instance, in this example I want to compare the difference in death probability if all the rats had been in litter 5, and likewise for litter 25.

I have attempted to repurpose some code from the `riskRegression:::predictRisk.coxph.penal()` function to create a function of my own. The code behind the predictRisk function for cox regressions is accessed using this code:

```
# access risk regression code
riskRegression:::predictRisk.coxph.penal
```

My reasoning is if I can retrieve the baseline hazard at time t, the linear equation of predictors and the frailty for that group, I should be able to calculate the survival probability for each observation at time t. This is using the equation:

exp(-bhValue)^ (exp(frailval) * exp(linearPred[i])

However, it seems the difference in survival probabilities between the highest and lowest in my cohort is larger than I would expect (the current example is 11.5% vs 27.5%) making me think my current equation is wrong? I would really appreciate someone just proofing this code.

```
library(survival)
library(riskRegression)
library(tidyverse)

rats <-  data.frame(rats)
rats$litter <- as.factor(rats$litter)
rats$sex <- as.factor(rats$sex)
rats$rx <- as.factor(rats$rx)

coxph.me <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ rx + sex + frailty(litter), 
                  data = rats)

frailty_risk <- function (object, cluster, frail_group, df){

  ### get specific frailty value ###
  effects_list <- as.data.frame(object$frail)
  # Get the group levels
  group_levels <- levels(df[[cluster]])
  # Combine the group levels with the frailty estimates
  effects_list <- data.frame(Group = group_levels, frailty = effects_list) %>% filter(Group == paste(frail_group))
  
  print(effects_list[,2])
  # retrive the frailty value
  frailval <- as.numeric(effects_list[, 2])

  ### define linear combination of predictors ###
  linearPred <- predict(object, newdata = df, se.fit = FALSE, 
                        conf.int = FALSE)

  ### retrieve baseline hazard at maximum time ###
  basehaz <- basehaz(object) %>% filter(time == max(time))
  bhValue <- basehaz[, 1] #retrive baseline hazard value

  ### apply the equation for survival probability ###
  # append to a dataframe each observation's surv prob
  survPred <- do.call("rbind", lapply(1:NROW(df),
                                      # apply the equation for surv probability
                                      function(i) {
                                        (exp(-bhValue)^ (exp(frailval) * exp(linearPred[i])))
                                    }))
  # calculate mean survPred from cohort
  p <- mean(survPred)
  # calculate probabilty of death
  return(1-p)

}


frailty_risk(coxph.me, 'litter', '5', rats)
frailty_risk(coxph.me, 'litter', '25', rats)
```